Не знаю как запустить программу из-за отсутствующего пакета
Пытаюсь скомпилировать свой проект:
go build .

В ответ получаю:
http_service/service.go:17:6: no required module provides package github.com/gofiber/template/html; to add it:
    go get github.com/gofiber/template/html

Пытаюсь загрузить модуль:
go get github.com/gofiber/template/html

На что получаю:
go: module github.com/gofiber/template@upgrade found (v1.8.3), but does not contain package github.com/gofiber/template/html

Что мне с этим делать?
Я новичек в использовании модулей.

Вероятно нужно указать версию в которой эта файл/папка был(а), в последней версии нет

@Daniil Loban, а как указать версию? Вручную в go.mod файле или как?

https://github.com/gofiber/template/tree/master/html попробуйте эту ссылку

@Daniil Loban, А куда класть пакет, если я использую модули? С использованием GO PATH все было понятно, есть структура папок, где лежат скачанные пакеты. А в данном случае куда размещать пакет?

Версии указываются после имени модуля через собачку go get github.com/gofiber/template/html@v1.2.3

Рядом с другими модулями которые у Вас есть разместите

@Daniil Loban, я набрал go get github.com/gofiber/template@v1.8.3, и после того как попытался скомпилировать код через go build . получил http_service/service.go:17:6: no required module provides package github.com/gofiber/template/html; to add it:  go get github.com/gofiber/template/html  . Согласно совету компилятора я ввел go get github.com/gofiber/template/html, на что получил go: module github.com/gofiber/template@upgrade found (v1.8.3), but does not contain package github.com/gofiber/template/html 

посмотрите эти примеры возможно Вам подойдут https://github.com/gofiber/template/blob/master/html/README.md
